# Set default header variables at all content off S3 or Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

i am new in AWS and i am trying to figure out how i can fix each file header variables.
To be more specific, i want to add following variables at all files that are served from cloudfront with origin s3:

- Cache-Control:public, max-age=10368000
- Expires:Fri, 27 Sep 2013 11:14:00 GMT
- Content-Encoding:gzip

I can add custom meta-data at each file (one by one) from aws bucket browsing (or by using a 3rd party software such cloudberry i can set http header variables and apply on every file via ftp), but i own lots of files and its not just that i want to set header variables on existing files but most important i need to automate this process, so next weeks updates wont need to be fixed separately.

Thanks,
c